# Undefined screen - Rhosync

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

Rhosync works fine for the demo application(**employee application**). I am able to login and then perform CRUD operations.

However, when I create my own project, add source adapters and add few screens, and then run the application, I find **undefined screen** when I go from first to second screen.

```
  # GET /Categories
  def index
    @categorieses = Categories.find(:all)
    render 
  end
```

On debugging I find that after **render**, undefined screen comes out.
Has someone experienced such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
render :action => :index
```

Also, sometimes the undefined screen can be fixed by using redirect instead of render.

```
redirect 'index'
```

Comment: render and redirect are not synonyms, they do different things.  Render will load the specified view, with any instance variables already defined. Redirect will execute the controller method pertaining to the specified action and then render the specified view, not simply show the view.

Comment: @Dan please suggest a better one if you have another aproach. Thanks!

Comment: There's not a better solution given the limited information in the question. The `render` modification is a fair guess, but redirect is just plain wrong. See @Geoffrey's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Calling **render** with no other arguments will look for a view file called `index.erb` (as defined by RhoMobile [convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration), derived from the name of the controller method) for the model `Categories`.  Ensure you have an `index.erb` file in the `/app/Categories/` folder.

[Here](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/ui#advanced-usage-of-render) is a link to the RhoMobile documentation on the usage of **render**.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible reason for this might also be that you don't have the necessary `<div>`s in your view code.

Remember that you're supposed to always have:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content"> your own content </div>
</div>
```

I just spent too much time figuring this out and this is the first hit on Google for "RhoMobile undefined" at the moment, so I'm adding in case someone else finds this question. :)